# Signing my applet with trusted certificate

Tags: java, jar, applet, certificate

I recently made an applet and when I embedded it into my site Java blocks it because it is not signed by a trusted authority.

I have downloaded a certification from CACert (.crt & .cer files) and I have my jar file (FollowMe.jar).

After a few hours searching on google how to sign the jar file with the crt file I'm still not able to do it. Could someone please help me? This is so frustrating.

Comment: Please add more information to help others to help you. e.g. how you signed it, any code, links to sites you tried to use.

Answer (score 1):

To sign a jar you need a keystore with a private key (normally on [`PCKS12`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) or [`JKS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystore) format) in your question it's not clear to me if you have a private key or not since you comment that:

> I have downloaded a certification from CACert

It's sounds confusing to me, anywise I assume that you have a correct keystore, due to sign a jar you can use the follow instruction using `jarsigner` which is found in `$JAVA_HOME/bin`:

```
jarsigner -keystore [yourKeystore] -storeType [PKCS12 or JKS] [yourApplet.jar] [keyAlias]
```

If like I suspect you're trying to sign the jar with a certificate without private key you've to know that this is not possible, you need a private key to perform this operation. You've the follow options:

1. Generate a keypair with selfsigned certificate using `keytool` (which is also in `$JAVA_HOME/bin`) with a command like follows:

`keytool -genkey -keyalg [RSA or another] -alias [yourkeyalias] -keystore [yourkeystore.jks] -storepass [keystorePassword] -validity [validity period for your certificate in days] -keysize [key size for algorithm in RSA for example 2048]`

Then fill the prompts about the subjectDN of your certificate.

Note that with the selfsigned certificate you can generate a keystore to make a test to sign your jar however in order that jvm recognize your applet as trusted you cannot sign the applet with a self signed certificate, instead you've to sign it with a key and a certificate signed with a trusted certificate authority for java code signing. So see the second option.

2. Generate a key and a `csr` (certificate signing request) and make a request to a certificate authority which generates code signing java certificates to sign your `csr` and generate a certificate. Then put the certificate, key, and cert chain to the keystore and sign the jar file with the jarsigner command. You can see the instructions in one of many java code signing vendors like [`Symantec`](http://www.symantec.com/code-signing/java/),[`Thawte`](https://www.thawte.com/code-signing/content-signing-certificates/sun-java/),[`Digicert`](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/oracle-java.htm),[`Globalsign`](https://www.globalsign.eu/code-signing-tool/),[`Entrust`](http://www.entrust.net/code-signing/index.htm) or some others (you can make a search through google :).

Hope this helps,

Comment: @kyriacoss finally this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

The below is a common way of doing things:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias appletCert -file CAcert.crt
jarsigner "C:\path\FollowMe.jar" appletCert
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for the reply. I tried the command and it's giving me an error: "Illegal option - jarsigner"

Comment: shoot there should be a new line

jarsigner "C:\path\FollowMe.jar" appletCert

Comment: @anonymous You didn't format it correctly. It is also nonsense. Unless there is a private key with that alias it won't work, and if there was a private key you wouldn't need the `-trustcacerts` parameter.